# Django Join Query - Show Only Categories With One Post or More

Tags: python, django

Hi I'm trying to get some help on a join query.

I have a Deals model and a Retailer model.  The Retailer model is a foreign key of my Deals model.  Looks like this

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=140, unique=True)
    description = RichTextUploadingField(default='')
    retailer = models.ForeignKey(Retailer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = VersatileImageField('deal image',
                               upload_to=deal_upload_path,
                               null=True,
                               blank=True)
    img_alt = models.CharField(max_length=140, default='')
    link = models.URLField(max_length=2000, default='')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    date_expires = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    secondary_price = models.CharField(max_length=140, default='')
    likes_total = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    expired = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    handpicked = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Retailer(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

I'm just trying to get a list of my retailers that have at least one deal.

I have a context_processor that looks like this but I'm having a hard time determining the best way to change this to what i need.  Any ideas?

```
def retailers(request):
    return {
        'stores': Retailer.objects.all().order_by('company')
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`exclude()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude) with Deal's [`related_query_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) and [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) lookup:

```
Retailer.objects.exclude(deal__isnull=True).order_by('company')
```

**UPD**

You can also use `filter` to combine as many conditions as you need, and `distinct` to remove dups from result:

```
Retailer.objects.filter(deal__isnull=False, deal__date_expires__gte=today).order_by('company').distinct()
```

Comment: i did try this...which seems close but for some reason is showing a few retailers with no deals and not showing some with deals   `Retailer.objects.annotate(c=Count('deal')).filter(c__gt=1).order_by('company')`

Comment: Yeah I don't think you're able to filter like that, because there's no "deal" column in the SQL.

Comment: i know what issue was-- i forgot that I am excluding expiring deals..i changed query to this, but it is listing the retailer every time there is a (non-expired) deal...see what i might be doing wrong?   `Retailer.objects.exclude(deal__isnull=True).filter(deal__date_expires__gte=today).order_by('company')`

Comment: @SamBobel it's working. Check `related_query_name` documentation. Django will do SQL join automatically.

Comment: tried it that way too, but i keep getting the retailer names repeated for each deal...

Comment: That did it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this is using Annotations. [Django ORM Cookbook](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/order_by_annotated_field.html) has a great section on this.

```py
from django.db.models import Count

queryset = Retailer.objects.annotate(
    deal_count=Count('deal')
).exclude(deal_count=0)
```

That adds a field that you can then use like any other.